# JobIntentService repeat in time

Tags: java, android

I want to use a JobIntentService for sending requests to a server every x time. The problem is that in versions before 26 of android it works perfectly with AlarmManager but in the most recent versions it doesn't.

```
public class ExampleJobIntentService extends JobIntentService {
private static final String TAG = "ExampleJobIntentService";

static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
    enqueueWork(context, ExampleJobIntentService.class, 123, work);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onHandleWork");

    String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, input + " - " + i);

        if (isStopped()) return;

        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    Intent serIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleJobIntentService.class);
    serIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", Singleton.getInstance().getWord());

    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, serIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmSer = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmSer.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, alarmIntent);
}

@Override
public boolean onStopCurrentWork() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStopCurrentWork");
    return super.onStopCurrentWork();
}
```

}

This in android VM of 24 is going very well but in 29 it enters the "onCreate" but it doesn't get to run the "onHandleWork", I guess because it doesn't run "enqueueWork".

Creating a new intent with ExampleJobIntentService works but it does it very fast:

```
Intent serIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleJobIntentService.class);
serIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", Singleton.getInstance().getWord());

ExampleJobIntentService.enqueueWork(this, serIntent);
```

I want it to wake up after a minute for example. Also as a last resort I could pause it but I would prefer to be able to create an alarm.

If you know any other way, you are also welcome. Thank you very much.